# Is the a way to make hp-scan or scanimage to automatically select de right area to scan?

Tags: scanner, mint, hplip, sane

I'm trying to make an non network scanner to work with linux running via command line and hiding it with php/html. The commands to scan hp-scan and scanimage are working well but they don't automatically select the non blank are to scan. For example if I scan a business card (85mm x 58mm) it scans the entire scanner area. Does sane have an utility to fix that?
I am using ubuntu 13 and mint 16.

```
scanimage --mode Color --resolution 100 --progress --compression JPEG --jpeg-quality 80 --format=tiff | convert tiff:- teste.jpg
```

Comment: which commands are you using?

Comment: This is one: sudo scanimage -p --mode=Color --compression=JPEG --jpeg-quality=80 --resolution=100 --format=tiff | convert tiff:- test.jpg

Comment: where did you find the "--jpeg-quality" option document?  My man page does not list it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also using X*Y coordinates when using scanimage. For your use case, I would have used the following command:

```
scanimage --progress  --format tiff --mode Color --resolution 300 -l 0mm -t 0mm -x 85mm -y 58mm | convert - -resize 50% -quality 75 teste.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already set sane as server for remote scan.